# Unable to Deploy to Heroku with Grunt Task on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I went installed something called half-pipe into my application. I can't seem to get it to work right. When I deploy it to Heroku, I receive an error.

```
$ gph heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 87, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 16.74 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 68 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.1
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/d-i/half-pipe.git
       Fetching git://github.com/joefiorini/sass-css-importer.git
       Using minitest (5.3.3)
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using rake (10.3.1)
       Using thread_safe (0.3.3)
       Using builder (3.2.2)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.4)
       Using arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
       Using browser (0.4.1)
       Using addressable (2.3.6)
       Using geocoder (1.2.0)
       Using referer-parser (0.2.1)
       Using request_store (1.0.5)
       Using bcrypt (3.1.7)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.19.1)
       Using daemons (1.1.9)
       Using orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Using eventmachine (1.0.3)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using multi_json (1.9.2)
       Using gravtastic (3.2.6)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sass (3.2.19)
       Using mysql2 (0.3.15)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using tzinfo (1.1.0)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using rdoc (4.1.1)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using warden (1.2.3)
       Using uglifier (2.5.0)
       Using ahoy_matey (0.1.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using sprockets (2.11.0)
       Using thin (1.6.2)
       Using activesupport (4.1.0)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using sdoc (0.4.0)
       Using actionview (4.1.0)
       Using activemodel (4.1.0)
       Using intercom-rails (0.2.24)
       Using jbuilder (2.0.6)
       Using actionpack (4.1.0)
       Using activerecord (4.1.0)
       Using rails-observers (0.1.2)
       Using actionmailer (4.1.0)
       Using railties (4.1.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
       Using activeresource (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using devise (3.2.4)
       Using rails (4.1.0)
       Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.3)
       Using turbolinks (2.2.2)
       Using wistia-api (0.2.3)
       Using sass-css-importer (1.0.0.beta.0) from git://github.com/joefiorini/sass-css-importer.git (at load-paths)
       Using half-pipe (0.3.0.beta.2) from git://github.com/d-i/half-pipe.git (at master)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (9.12s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       executing: "/tmp/build_14997ed5-86be-4fb4-bc2a-ec8003a546db/node_modules/.bin/grunt build:public"
       rake aborted!
       Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_14997ed5-86be-4fb4-bc2a-ec8003a546db/node_modules/.bin/grunt
       /tmp/build_14997ed5-86be-4fb4-bc2a-ec8003a546db/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/half-pipe-8f75b3dcedd0/lib/tasks/assets.rake:16:in `exec'
       /tmp/build_14997ed5-86be-4fb4-bc2a-ec8003a546db/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/half-pipe-8f75b3dcedd0/lib/tasks/assets.rake:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_14997ed5-86be-4fb4-bc2a-ec8003a546db/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/half-pipe-8f75b3dcedd0/lib/tasks/assets.rake:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => half_pipe:execute_grunt_command
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Within my app, the `node_modules/bin/grunt` file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

process.title = 'grunt';
n.
// Especially badass external libs.
var findup = require('findup-sync');
var resolve = require('resolve').sync;

// Internal libs.
var options = require('../lib/cli').options;
var completion = require('../lib/completion');
var info = require('../lib/info');
var path = require('path');


var basedir = process.cwd();
var gruntpath;

// Do stuff based on CLI options.
if ('completion' in options) {
  completion.print(options.completion);
} else if (options.version) {
  info.version();
} else if (options.base && !options.gruntfile) {
  basedir = path.resolve(options.base);
} else if (options.gruntfile) {
  basedir = path.resolve(path.dirname(options.gruntfile));
}

try {
  gruntpath = resolve('grunt', {basedir: basedir});
} catch (ex) {
  gruntpath = findup('lib/grunt.js');
  // No grunt install found!
  if (!gruntpath) {
    if (options.version) { process.exit(); }
    if (options.help) { info.help(); }
    info.fatal('Unable to find local grunt.', 99);
  }
}

// Everything looks good. Require local grunt and run it.
require(gruntpath).cli();
```

I'm not sure whaat half-pipe is doing. I'm also confused on what the error means. If anyone can give me some pointers on what code is need to help solve the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue just now.

The solution that worked for us was to simply to remove half-pipe from the Gemfile.
Basically all the useful things that half-pipe does are in the generator.
Once you are done with the generator and configured your Grunt etc., - you don't need half-pipe any more.

So the steps are:

1. Remove half-pipe from the Gemfile
2. bundle update
3. disable asset compilation by adding the following line to your config/application.rb: `config.assets.enabled = false`
4. Test that everything still works fine by doing `grunt server`, `grunt build:public` and then `rails s`
5. Make sure the files that `grunt build:public` created are added to the repo: `git add -A`
6. Finally push to Heroku as normal

Hope this works for others as well.